# How to remove the price line in light-weight-chart?

Tags: lightweight-charts

I have implemented tradingview's lightweight chart in my app, and the chart looks [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LLlxc.png). There is a dotted horizontal line for the last price.

Is it possible to hide the horizontal line?

Comment: You're referring to the 'Baseline' of a series. According to the Tradingview documentation a price line is something completely different, see: https://tradingview.github.io/lightweight-charts/tutorials/how_to/price-line

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When creating the series, you can set the `priceLineVisible` option to false to disable that line.

```js
const mainSeries = chart.addLineSeries({
    priceLineVisible: false,
});
```

Documentation: https://tradingview.github.io/lightweight-charts/docs/api/interfaces/SeriesOptionsCommon#pricelinevisible

Answer (score 0):

For removing ltp dotted line in your chart you should set priceLineVisible to false in addAreaSeries.

```
 var areaSeries = chart.addAreaSeries({
  priceLineVisible: false,
  topColor: this.config.topColor,
  bottomColor: this.config.bottomColor,
  lineColor: this.config.lineColor,
  lineWidth: this.config.lineWidth,
});
```